# External monitor not working after starting in safe mode

Tags: laptop, display, external-display, safe-mode

I was having some troubles with my computer's antivirus so I had to restart my computer in safe mode. It successfully booted back up but my external monitor I have to use isn't working when I plug it in. This is a huge problem because I need to use that monitor if I want to use my computer as my laptop screen is broken. I really hope I don't need to do a lot to fix this.

Comment: what laptop are you using?

Comment: Im not sure, its HP but I'm not sure what the model is

Answer (score 0):

Try your Windows + monitor switch keys; usually <kbd>Win + F4</kbd> or <kbd>Win + F5</kbd> keys.

Tap these two key together, and wait for a few seconds, as the switch might take a bit longer.

Try repeating these as there are 4-options through which you will need to cycle.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm rather certain that you can't attach an external monitor in safe mode, does this also occur when booting normally? If so, try hitting windows key + P
Then hit right arrow and enter, if nothing occurs, try it again, 3 to 4 times.